# how to get http responses continuously to a java application?

Tags: java, php, netbeans-7, httpresponse, scheduler

I have the coding shown below where I have sheduled to get a http response from a php web server page.

```
public static void stopPHPDataChecker() {      
        canStop=true;
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    // http request to the php page and get the response
    PHPDataChecker pdc = new PHPDataChecker();
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    final ScheduledFuture<?> pdcHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(pdc, 0L, 10L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);// Start schedule
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(">> TRY TO STOP!!!");
            pdcHandle.cancel(true);
            Sheduler.stopPHPDataChecker();
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }

    }, 1L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

   do {
        if (canStop) {
            scheduler.shutdown();

        }
    } while (!canStop);

    System.out.println("END");
}
```

this coding only returns one response but I want it to get responses continuously so i can do different tasks according to the returned value. how can i do it? 
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-** My simple suggestion will be using Thread, which will send a request to the webservice after a regular interval of time, and receive the response.

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

          public void run(){

   while(isDone){  

             //isDone is the boolean variable which will help u end the Thread.

            // SEND THE REQUEST 

try{

  Thread.sleep(5000);   // Delay of 5 seconds before the request is fired again

   }catch(Exception ex){

           ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
   }

    });

 t.start();

 t.join();   // Use join() to block the process further till the response arrives.
```

Comment: thank you for your simple solution for this! it was helpfull alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheduler.stopPHPDataChecker();
```

inside the run method makes canStop= true , and

```
if (canStop) {
    scheduler.shutdown();

}
```

makes the scheduler to shutdown.Removing the stopPHP.. method from run method will solve this.You may have re factor the code.Looks confusing.

Answer (score 0):

To receive an answer you have to post a request...

Each time !

Put the request post into your periodic loop.